# .Net Web Application Redesign - Recommendations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

My employer has a 9 year old proprietary .Net Web Application that needs redesigned.  Its creation was originally outsourced to another company and its architecture and coding were done very poorly. It was designed in ASP.net 1.14, VB.Net, and C#.  We continued building on the poor architecture, improving when and where possible.  We have upgraded to ASP.Net 4.0 and VS 2010.

The system is only used internally and nearly all business processes and workflows are handled through the system for about 140 users.  However, the system has grown so big it has become difficult to maintain and its architecture makes it difficult include new functionality in line with the latest technology.

If you could design a .Net system from scratch, **keeping mobile technology and Windows 8 in mind**, how would you do it?  Our SQL 2008 database is sound and we do not intend to change anything there.

.Net Webforms or MVC?

What architecture would you use?  Examples?  We would need to allow for a customizable business logic layer in the event that an external company with different business rules uses the system.

Any recommended books on designing from the ground floor up?

Other considerations?

Comment: This site is for specific programming questions and answers. Open ended questions and opinion/survey questions are not really in the spirit of the site. If you could reformulate this to match the former, you may get a better response.

Comment: Hi StingyJack, I totally agree with you. Is there a stack site for more architecture type questions? That would actually be very helpful. Won't be the most frequented, but certainly useful.

Comment: I don't see one on the stack exchange that necessarily fits the "Architecture" billing, and you have already alluded to what is probably a good starting point for OP to look in.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a limited answer, but based on my experience I would say the following... If you're going for a rewrite:

- Use MVC 4x.

  - Web Forms are outdated now. If you look at their original purpose you will notice that they were built with existing windows forms developers in mind (button events etc.).
  - MVC is more of an evolution of target audience, because web developers have matured to the degree where they realise how important standards are and hence require an environment that will allow them to produce the kind of results modern platforms require. It is also far stronger in the separation of concerns arena with things like unit testing.

For the business layer I would seriously consider Web Services, or in your case WCF. This will allow you to deal with a varied number of situations in the future including business to business scenarios where other companies might want to integrate directly with your internal system.

**Other Advice?**

We've been involved with quite a few systems over the years where we've adopted someone else's system. Whether badly written/designed, or just outdated, starting from scratch is always difficult and you should pay serious attention to the following:

- Budget - How much is the company really prepared to fork out
- User Temperament: If you are working with users who don't like change, then this is an area where you should pay special attention. Get them involved in the process so that they feel that the outcome was as much their doing as yours.

  - Be careful of loss of functionality. Because of time/money constraints you may redevelop something but end up not having the time or money to implement what you considered a minor feature. On deployment your users become agitated because it was in fact a pretty serious piece of functionality. The net result is that they start to loose confidence in the system and you'll pay dearly for that.
- Processes: If you can consider Agile as a development strategy. It doesn't lend itself well to smaller projects, but does make a big difference in bigger long terms projects if implemented correctly.
- Skills/Resources: Be sure that your team are utilized affectively and have the right skills for the right job.

Wow I could say so much more, but it would take a day or two.

Hope that helps a small amount.

Regards,
Jacques

Comment: Thank you for the response, Jacques.  I now understand this probably wasn't the best place to ask my question but I appreciate your help despite that.  It is a good starting point at least.